# Solve for X sandwiched between 2 lower triangular matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations, numerical-linear-algebra

Given $L, K$ are n by n are lower triangular matrix. $B$ is general n by n matrix. How can I write an algorithm for solving for $X$  in $LXK = B $. I have written an algorithm for simple $Lx = b$ using back substitution and solving for x. Is there a way I can relate that to the current problem at hand: $LXK = B$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Using [vectorization and Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product#Matrix_equations) $LXK=B$ is equivalent to solving 
$$(K^T\otimes L)\mathrm{vec}(X)=\mathrm{vec}(B).$$ 
Thanks to the structure of $L$ and $K$, the matrix $K^T\otimes L$ has also a special structure (upper block triangular with lower triangular blocks).

Comment: Can you provide some beginner level explanation for this or suggest another method that is simpler?

Answer (score 0):

For $Lx=b$

For simplicity lets take an example and solve it in the case $n=3$

$L=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
-1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 2 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3
\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1  \\ 2 \\ 3
\end{pmatrix}$

Thus we solve it by multiplying what is on the left hand side by each other and we get that

$\begin{aligned}
x_1 &=1 \\
-x_1+x_2 &= 2 \\
2x_2 +x_3 &=3
\end{aligned} $

Comment: Thanks for the help @fareed AF. However, the question was not clear previously. I have updated it now. Can you share what do you think about the updated problem?